# Integral solution of a differential equation (verification)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to verify that the integral $$y(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-t - \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right) dt$$ satisfies the ODE $$xy''' + 2y = 0$$ ($x > 0$). Differentiating under the integral sign three times gives $$y''' = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t \sqrt{t}}\exp\left(-t - \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$$ In this form it's not obvious that this satisifes the above equation. I guess I need to use integration by parts to simplify the above integral but I can't quite see how that works. If I let $u = \exp(-t - \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}})$ and $v' = \frac{1}{t \sqrt{t}}$ then $v = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{t}}$ and $u' = \left(-1 + \frac{x}{2t\sqrt{t}}\right)\exp(-t - \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}})$ and the above becomes $$y''' = \int_0^\infty \frac{-2}{\sqrt{t}} \left(-1 + \frac{x}{2t\sqrt{t}}\right)\exp\left(-t - \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right) \, dt$$ and this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone provide me with help? Hopefully I'm not just making a mistake with the differentiation/integration.

Comment: I changed \textrm{exp} to \exp.  That not only prevents italicization but also provides proper spacing in expressions like $a\exp b$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: Why would you differentiate three times?

Comment: Should the equation be $xy'''+2y=0$?

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $$y'(x) =  - \int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt t }}\exp } \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt$$

and then $$y'''(x) = -\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{t\sqrt t}\exp } \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt$$

Now, note that then we have $$xy''' + 2y = \int_0^\infty  {\left( {2 - \frac{x}{{t\sqrt t }}} \right)\exp \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt} $$

Now, write this as $$xy''' + 2y =  - 2\int_0^\infty  {\left( {-1 + \frac{x}{{2t\sqrt t }}} \right)\exp \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt} $$ and note that$$\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right) =  - 1 + \frac{x}{2{t\sqrt t }}$$

Can you continue? Note that the integration bounds should collapse since $$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to {0^ + }} \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right) =  - \infty   \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty } \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right) =  - \infty  \cr} $$

**ADD** If you want to make this a little more clear, split at the point where the function is zero, namely $$\int_0^{{{\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}^{2/3}}} {\left( { - 1 + \frac{x}{{2t\sqrt t }}} \right)\exp \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt}  + \int_{{{\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}^{2/3}}}^\infty  {\left( { - 1 + \frac{x}{{2t\sqrt t }}} \right)\exp \left( { - t - \frac{x}{{\sqrt t }}} \right)dt} $$

Then we have under the same substitution this is $$\int_{ - \infty }^0 {\exp udu}  + \int_0^{ - \infty } {\exp udu}  = 0$$

Comment: I see now. Thanks. So integration by parts wasn't necessary after all...